# getting 404 error on routing to bar1 page from the graphs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pug, passport-local

the error is 
NOT FOUND
 404
Error: Not Found
  at Layer.app.use.res.render.message[as handle] (c:\node\nodetest1\app.js:48|15)
  at trim-prefix (c:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:240:15)
  at C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\router\inder.js:208.9
  at Function.proto.process_params(C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:269:12)
  at next (C:\node\nodetest1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:199:19)

---

```
The router.js 



enter code here
router.get('/graphs',function(req,res)
{
 res.render('graphs');
 var db = req.db;
 var collection = db.get('env1);
 var env = req.body.env1;
 var envo = req.body.nodeno;
 collection.find({"envno":env,"env":envo},{},function(e,docs)
 {
   if(e)
   {
     console.log(e);
   }
   else
   {
    res.render('bar1',{"table":docs});
   });
  });
router.get('/bar1',function(req,res)
{
   res.render('bar1');
});
```

when routing from graphs to bar1 I get a 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be you trying to route to "graph/bar1" so try

```
router.get('/graphs/bar1',function(req,res)
{
   res.render('bar1');
});
```

Comment: can you copy paste the line where there is an error?

Comment: I am not able to identify that only

Comment: the about is router function in which graphs is used to take values from the user and search for thoses values in the database and make a json object which is given to bar1 page which contains the a bargraphs and use thoses values to display it in graph form

Comment: @KaushikHs Please don't accept an answer if it doesn't work for you accepting an answer means that your problem is solved to other users and you may not get better answers from other users.